# What does "a time that never was" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, time

Please explain what "a time that never was" means.

The context:

She glanced to the three who stood to one side of the King's throne, looking as though they'd stepped out of paintings **from a time that never was**.

Comment: It means a time (moment) that never existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Time* in this context means the following:

> **Time** *noun*
>   2.4 (also times) A portion of time in history or characterized by particular events or circumstances: *Victorian times*, *at the time of Galileo*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/time)

Literally, *from a time that never was* means that the period/era in question referenced never existed. However, the context refers to the appearance of *the three*, who are as real as *She* and *the King's throne*.

Putting this together, it would be fair to conclude that the hypothetical painting was set in a **mythological or otherwise fictional time period**.

Comment: Thank you so much Lawrence for your explanation. I've got it now.

Comment: @Nhu_Doan You're welcome. Glad to help.